# Fast source of high quality randomness

Tags: random

Evolution algorithm is highly dependent on good randomness. Unfortunately, good randomness sources are slow (and hence the AI).

Question is, if I take one highest quality number and use it as a seed for poor quality (but fast) random generator, how much 'random' will be result?

Comment: This question is kind of broad. You might find better answers on the [Mathematics Stack Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I think your question is more scientific. Most of random generators, as I know, are predefined values and seed is used to change order of sampling from this array of values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have conducted some research into this area previously. Evolutionary algorithms are part of a family of meta heuristic algorithms of which the particle swarm algorithm also belongs. A study has been conducted into the effectiveness of random number generators on the particle swarm algorithm here: [Impact of the quality of random numbers generators on the performance of particle swarm optimization](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/?arnumber=5346366). It should directly apply to your evolutionary algorithm.